# Rails reset password email is not triggering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I know this was repeated question that was posted by may other people. I have tired of tried with different solution, but noting works for me. I have integrated Devise with my application. For reset password I am using default Devise methods. So when I try to reset my password, the Devise::Mailer#reset_password_instructions: processed outbound mail is executing from console but I didn't receive email from the application.

This is the email set configured with the application **config/initializers/setup_mailer.rb**

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smpt.gmail.com",
    :port => "587",
    :domain => "ipaddress",
    :user_name => "*****",
    :password => "*****",
    :authentication => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Output from console

```
Devise::Mailer#reset_password_instructions: processed outbound mail in 10.4ms
Sent mail to sethunagakarthi.m@irco.com (4.3ms)
Date: Fri, 27 Apr 2018 11:11:34 +0530
From: PyraMIDtool@irco.com
Reply-To: PyraMIDtool@irco.com
To: sethunagakarthi.m@irco.com
Message-ID: <5ae2b80e7e502_34142b2a9a15f8fc349e3@iradmin-OptiPlex-3040.mail>
Subject: Reset password instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Hello sethunagakarthi.m@irco.com!</p>

<p>Someone has requested a link to change your password. You can do this through the link below.</p>

<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=nN_7q6hTJETUzLM4jNeM">Change my password</a></p>

<p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
<p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
Completed 302 Found in 322ms (ActiveRecord: 285.2ms)
```

devise.rb

```
# Use this hook to configure devise mailer, warden hooks and so forth.
# Many of these configuration options can be set straight in your model.
Devise.setup do |config|
  # The secret key used by Devise. Devise uses this key to generate
  # random tokens. Changing this key will render invalid all existing
  # confirmation, reset password and unlock tokens in the database.
  # Devise will use the `secret_key_base` as its `secret_key`
  # by default. You can change it below and use your own secret key.
  # config.secret_key = '94b46ce945cf69c1b34d34da55436d8020a2f43490728cc999076ff34e963a446e8513e2c353c6eb50c2963aeaa2560b1f292171f0bacba88070c104c2551815'

  # ==> Mailer Configuration
  # Configure the e-mail address which will be shown in Devise::Mailer,
  # note that it will be overwritten if you use your own mailer class
  # with default "from" parameter.
  config.mailer_sender = 'PyraMIDtool@irco.com'

  # Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
  config.mailer = 'Devise::Mailer'

  # Configure the parent class responsible to send e-mails.
  # config.parent_mailer = 'ActionMailer::Base'

  # ==> ORM configuration
  # Load and configure the ORM. Supports :active_record (default) and
  # :mongoid (bson_ext recommended) by default. Other ORMs may be
  # available as additional gems.
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'

  # ==> Configuration for any authentication mechanism
  # Configure which keys are used when authenticating a user. The default is
  # just :email. You can configure it to use [:username, :subdomain], so for
  # authenticating a user, both parameters are required. Remember that those
  # parameters are used only when authenticating and not when retrieving from
  # session. If you need permissions, you should implement that in a before filter.
  # You can also supply a hash where the value is a boolean determining whether
  # or not authentication should be aborted when the value is not present.
  config.authentication_keys = [:corp_id]

  # Configure parameters from the request object used for authentication. Each entry
  # given should be a request method and it will automatically be passed to the
  # find_for_authentication method and considered in your model lookup. For instance,
  # if you set :request_keys to [:subdomain], :subdomain will be used on authentication.
  # The same considerations mentioned for authentication_keys also apply to request_keys.
  # config.request_keys = []

  # Configure which authentication keys should be case-insensitive.
  # These keys will be downcased upon creating or modifying a user and when used
  # to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]

  # Configure which authentication keys should have whitespace stripped.
  # These keys will have whitespace before and after removed upon creating or
  # modifying a user and when used to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email]

  # Tell if authentication through request.params is enabled. True by default.
  # It can be set to an array that will enable params authentication only for the
  # given strategies, for example, `config.params_authenticatable = [:database]` will
  # enable it only for database (email + password) authentication.
  # config.params_authenticatable = true

  # Tell if authentication through HTTP Auth is enabled. False by default.
  # It can be set to an array that will enable http authentication only for the
  # given strategies, for example, `config.http_authenticatable = [:database]` will
  # enable it only for database authentication. The supported strategies are:
  # :database      = Support basic authentication with authentication key + password
  # config.http_authenticatable = false

  # If 401 status code should be returned for AJAX requests. True by default.
  # config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = true

  # The realm used in Http Basic Authentication. 'Application' by default.
  # config.http_authentication_realm = 'Application'

  # It will change confirmation, password recovery and other workflows
  # to behave the same regardless if the e-mail provided was right or wrong.
  # Does not affect registerable.
  # config.paranoid = true

  # By default Devise will store the user in session. You can skip storage for
  # particular strategies by setting this option.
  # Notice that if you are skipping storage for all authentication paths, you
  # may want to disable generating routes to Devise's sessions controller by
  # passing skip: :sessions to `devise_for` in your config/routes.rb
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]

  # By default, Devise cleans up the CSRF token on authentication to
  # avoid CSRF token fixation attacks. This means that, when using AJAX
  # requests for sign in and sign up, you need to get a new CSRF token
  # from the server. You can disable this option at your own risk.
  # config.clean_up_csrf_token_on_authentication = true

  # When false, Devise will not attempt to reload routes on eager load.
  # This can reduce the time taken to boot the app but if your application
  # requires the Devise mappings to be loaded during boot time the application
  # won't boot properly.
  # config.reload_routes = true

  # ==> Configuration for :database_authenticatable
  # For bcrypt, this is the cost for hashing the password and defaults to 11. If
  # using other algorithms, it sets how many times you want the password to be hashed.
  #
  # Limiting the stretches to just one in testing will increase the performance of
  # your test suite dramatically. However, it is STRONGLY RECOMMENDED to not use
  # a value less than 10 in other environments. Note that, for bcrypt (the default
  # algorithm), the cost increases exponentially with the number of stretches (e.g.
  # a value of 20 is already extremely slow: approx. 60 seconds for 1 calculation).
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 11

  # Set up a pepper to generate the hashed password.
  # config.pepper = 'd937edcd8ba852daed548479e1a6ac22d6c7aefebacc316e0236e2362421b1258dc40d36a1766fda4f9db96bc9ea4b53cc43d6178b1b3f2b6e089588f724811d'

  # Send a notification to the original email when the user's email is changed.
  # config.send_email_changed_notification = false

  # Send a notification email when the user's password is changed.
  # config.send_password_change_notification = false

  # ==> Configuration for :confirmable
  # A period that the user is allowed to access the website even without
  # confirming their account. For instance, if set to 2.days, the user will be
  # able to access the website for two days without confirming their account,
  # access will be blocked just in the third day. Default is 0.days, meaning
  # the user cannot access the website without confirming their account.
  # config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 2.days

  # A period that the user is allowed to confirm their account before their
  # token becomes invalid. For example, if set to 3.days, the user can confirm
  # their account within 3 days after the mail was sent, but on the fourth day
  # their account can't be confirmed with the token any more.
  # Default is nil, meaning there is no restriction on how long a user can take
  # before confirming their account.
  # config.confirm_within = 3.days

  # If true, requires any email changes to be confirmed (exactly the same way as
  # initial account confirmation) to be applied. Requires additional unconfirmed_email
  # db field (see migrations). Until confirmed, new email is stored in
  # unconfirmed_email column, and copied to email column on successful confirmation.
  config.reconfirmable = true

  # Defines which key will be used when confirming an account
  # config.confirmation_keys = [:email]

  # ==> Configuration for :rememberable
  # The time the user will be remembered without asking for credentials again.
  # config.remember_for = 2.weeks

  # Invalidates all the remember me tokens when the user signs out.
  config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true

  # If true, extends the user's remember period when remembered via cookie.
  # config.extend_remember_period = false

  # Options to be passed to the created cookie. For instance, you can set
  # secure: true in order to force SSL only cookies.
  # config.rememberable_options = {}

  # ==> Configuration for :validatable
  # Range for password length.
  config.password_length = 6..128

  # Email regex used to validate email formats. It simply asserts that
  # one (and only one) @ exists in the given string. This is mainly
  # to give user feedback and not to assert the e-mail validity.
  config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/

  # ==> Configuration for :timeoutable
  # The time you want to timeout the user session without activity. After this
  # time the user will be asked for credentials again. Default is 30 minutes.
  # config.timeout_in = 30.minutes

  # ==> Configuration for :lockable
  # Defines which strategy will be used to lock an account.
  # :failed_attempts = Locks an account after a number of failed attempts to sign in.
  # :none            = No lock strategy. You should handle locking by yourself.
  # config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts

  # Defines which key will be used when locking and unlocking an account
  # config.unlock_keys = [:email]

  # Defines which strategy will be used to unlock an account.
  # :email = Sends an unlock link to the user email
  # :time  = Re-enables login after a certain amount of time (see :unlock_in below)
  # :both  = Enables both strategies
  # :none  = No unlock strategy. You should handle unlocking by yourself.
  # config.unlock_strategy = :both

  # Number of authentication tries before locking an account if lock_strategy
  # is failed attempts.
  # config.maximum_attempts = 20

  # Time interval to unlock the account if :time is enabled as unlock_strategy.
  config.unlock_in = 1.hour

  # Warn on the last attempt before the account is locked.
  # config.last_attempt_warning = true

  # ==> Configuration for :recoverable
  #
  # Defines which key will be used when recovering the password for an account
  config.reset_password_keys = [:email]

  # Time interval you can reset your password with a reset password key.
  # Don't put a too small interval or your users won't have the time to
  # change their passwords.
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours

  # When set to false, does not sign a user in automatically after their password is
  # reset. Defaults to true, so a user is signed in automatically after a reset.
  # config.sign_in_after_reset_password = true

  # ==> Configuration for :encryptable
  # Allow you to use another hashing or encryption algorithm besides bcrypt (default).
  # You can use :sha1, :sha512 or algorithms from others authentication tools as
  # :clearance_sha1, :authlogic_sha512 (then you should set stretches above to 20
  # for default behavior) and :restful_authentication_sha1 (then you should set
  # stretches to 10, and copy REST_AUTH_SITE_KEY to pepper).
  #
  # Require the `devise-encryptable` gem when using anything other than bcrypt
  # config.encryptor = :sha512

  # ==> Scopes configuration
  # Turn scoped views on. Before rendering "sessions/new", it will first check for
  # "users/sessions/new". It's turned off by default because it's slower if you
  # are using only default views.
  config.scoped_views = true

  # Configure the default scope given to Warden. By default it's the first
  # devise role declared in your routes (usually :user).
  # config.default_scope = :user

  # Set this configuration to false if you want /users/sign_out to sign out
  # only the current scope. By default, Devise signs out all scopes.
  # config.sign_out_all_scopes = true

  # ==> Navigation configuration
  # Lists the formats that should be treated as navigational. Formats like
  # :html, should redirect to the sign in page when the user does not have
  # access, but formats like :xml or :json, should return 401.
  #
  # If you have any extra navigational formats, like :iphone or :mobile, you
  # should add them to the navigational formats lists.
  #
  # The "*/*" below is required to match Internet Explorer requests.
  # config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html]

  # The default HTTP method used to sign out a resource. Default is :delete.
  config.sign_out_via = :delete

  # ==> OmniAuth
  # Add a new OmniAuth provider. Check the wiki for more information on setting
  # up on your models and hooks.
  # config.omniauth :github, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET', scope: 'user,public_repo'

  # ==> Warden configuration
  # If you want to use other strategies, that are not supported by Devise, or
  # change the failure app, you can configure them inside the config.warden block.
  #
  # config.warden do |manager|
  #   manager.intercept_401 = false
  #   manager.default_strategies(scope: :user).unshift :some_external_strategy
  # end

  # ==> Mountable engine configurations
  # When using Devise inside an engine, let's call it `MyEngine`, and this engine
  # is mountable, there are some extra configurations to be taken into account.
  # The following options are available, assuming the engine is mounted as:
  #
  #     mount MyEngine, at: '/my_engine'
  #
  # The router that invoked `devise_for`, in the example above, would be:
  # config.router_name = :my_engine
  #
  # When using OmniAuth, Devise cannot automatically set OmniAuth path,
  # so you need to do it manually. For the users scope, it would be:
  # config.omniauth_path_prefix = '/my_engine/users/auth'
end
```

This is my environment/development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.seconds.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Suppress logger output for asset requests.
  config.assets.quiet = true
  # SMTP setting for email
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  # SMTP settings for gmail
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :user_name            => "*******",
    :password             => "*******",
    :authentication       => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

  ENV["APPLICATION_URL"] = "http://localhost:3000"
  ENV["IP_ADDRESSS"] = "10.200.102.74"
  ENV["USER_NAME"] = "*****"
  ENV["PASSWORD"] = "*****"
  ENV["JENKINS_USERNAME"] = "******"
  ENV["JENKINS_PASSWORD"] = "******"

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Use an evented file watcher to asynchronously detect changes in source code,
  # routes, locales, etc. This feature depends on the listen gem.
  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
end
```

I would be grateful to you if some help me to escape from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? Put it in your environments/development.rb file

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: "gmail.com",
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: username@gmail.com,
    password: yourPass
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change the following line in your development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Now you are able to see the errors for mailer.

Comment: SocketError - getaddrinfo: Name or service not known this is what I am getting in console any suggestion for this please

Comment: Although this provides help in further debugging the issue but it doesn't directly provide a solution to the question.

Comment: One possible issue is, you are not able to connect with gmail or your access to gmail is blocked on your current network. Please check if you have access to gmail .